# Why am I getting SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"] in this integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm not sure why I'm getting the error message 
*"Throw::sysexc: Uncaught SystemException returned to top level. Can be caught with Catch[[Ellipsis], _SystemException]."* when trying to compute

```
Integrate[(1/(t (t - x))^(1/6)
 Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[1/6, 2/3, 3/2, t] + 4/27 t^(5/6)/(t - x)^(1/6)Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[7/6, 5/3, 5/2, t]), {t, x, 1}, Assumptions -> {0 < x < 1}]
```

Comment: I don't get that error but it looks like the integral doesn't converge anyway.  If you plot the integrand, it blows up at `t = x` and at `t = 1`.  FunctionExpand will get rid of the Hypergeometric functions, if you want to simplify a little.